# entity framework 4.1 exception types

Tags: entity-framework-4.1

What kind of exceptions should i handle when using the entity framework.  I noticed the `DbUpdateConcurrencyException`.  What about exceptions that occur when reading the data e.g database unavailable etc etc. Do i capture a `SqlException`?

Comment: Related to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4323439/catching-sql-exception-in-entity-framework4what-is-the-best-practice